# Command line for VLC to restream an internet m3u8 stream to a local m3u8

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, streaming, hls

does anyone know how to restream in VLC a source like http://server.com/test.m3u8 to local file like c:\temp\test.m3u8 ?

Saw some example here; https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/#HTTP_streaming

but I didn't see one for my situation. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: `how to restream` , i don't understand, you already get the stream with vlc on your local computer, why restream to local ? m3u8 is not the stream it's a file containing all parts of stream if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Hello, I would like to restream it out to an External server. The original m3u8 source I don't create. So I need to restream it onto a more powerful server which will be able to handle more load/users accessing it. As the source server will crash if too many people access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg to do that:

> ffmpeg -i http://server.com/test.m3u8 c:\temp\test.m3u8

Comment: Hello, I'm looking for a command line for VLC. There are some double deep links that ffmpeg cannot read properly but VLC does resolve it. Thanks